# Pointer to an element in boost pointer container

Tags: c++, boost, pointer-container

I am just starting to use `boost::ptr_vector`. I have a ptr_vector `pctr` as a member of one class A and want another class B to refer to an element in `pctr`. While constructing an object of class B I want to store a pointer in `pctr`.

Since pointer containers do not allow access to the pointer (but only to references), I must take the address of the reference from `pctr` and then store it in the object of type B. But taking the address of a reference seems unintuitive. Is there an better alternative?

Comment: Actually have the same issue. Will go back to my previous solution (vector of raw pointers with explicit delete). Silly, really.

Comment: @Cookie actually, till now (2011) I have been using pointer containers a lot. I use a reference_wrapper. I have explained this in the wiki of a project I am working on: http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/crackpot/index.php?title=Boost_Pointer_Containers

Comment: Good point, thanks. If you find yourself with some spare time, performance comparisons between the three alternatives might be nice.

Answer (score 2):

As you've discovered, the boost pointer containers guard their pointers well.
Sure, you can defeat it by taking the address of the references it will yield, but be aware that you may be diluting the strength of the pointer container's claim to authoritative ownership by hanging on to these pointers (all depends on the rest of your code really).

Alternatives would seem to be:

- Have class B hold iterators referencing the pointer container element of interest (of course usual iterator invalidation rules will have to be dealt with).
- Since A owns the pointers and you seem to want B to hold some sort of non-owning weak reference to it, use a container of `shared_ptr` instead, and have B use `weak_ptr`.  Downside might per performance.

Comment: Ya, I guess the rationale behind the design seems to be that since the ownership of the pointers is with A, B should not have a pointer, but a reference to an element within the pctr. In other words, B's declaration has to be based on the fact that the element within the pctr would always exist.

Comment: Although syntactic sugar, `reference_wrapper` might be just what the doctor prescribed. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/193703/how-is-tr1referencewrapper-useful

Answer (score 0):

I think taking the address of the dereferenced iterator is the correct way to achieve what you're trying to do.

```
iterator it = ...
T *ptr = &*it;
```

However, this is dangerous because you could end up with dangling pointers, if the A object is destroyed before B objects. This is why the [`release`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/ptr_container/doc/reversible_ptr_container.html#pointer-container-requirements) function, which lets the caller take the address of an object, also remove the pointer from the container.

If you can support the overhead, you might consider changing the `boost::ptr_vector` to a vector of smart pointers, e.g. `std::vector<boost::shared_ptr<T> >`.

Comment: The address of the iterator to a ptr_vector would change and become invalid if there is further insertion.

Comment: but the -1 is not from me (your statement about using vector of shared_ptrs makes sense).